# ASP.NET file rebasing with a reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net, proxy, reverse

We have a site hosted on a domain that is provided by a reverse proxy from a 3rd party. The proxy provides sends the url www.example.com/nl/test/ to our server where the site is hosted on.

The site itself uses frameworks like Telerik UI for ASP.NET Ajax and the Ajax Control Toolkit.
By default when the site is loaded all the scriptresources/themes files/images are being written with the path "/scriptresource.axd" "/image.gif" the reverse proxy from the 3rd party picks this up and tries to redirect files to wwww.example.com/defaulthomepage/.

So by default ASP.NET writes paths to the domain root which is not something we want in this scenario, it should point to /nl/test/ instead.

In order to prevent default method of writing file paths the URL Rewrite extension for IIS was installed. 
There are no a couple of rules in URL Rewriting which succesfully rewrite all the files to /nl/test/file.whatever but every time an Ajax request is made the following error occurs

> Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Is there a way to rebase the default file path of an ASP.NET site through code? We have already tried the base html tag.